# Playframework WS Api and Certificates

Tags: java, certificate, playframework-2.0

Does Play 2.0 WS API validate server certificates?
And if not, how i can validate it in Java?

Comment: on 01 oct 2012 play 2.0.4 was released and in the highlights i seen:
- Check SLL certificates in WS
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/e16pHojeSvs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [issue open](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/655-ws-call-wont-fail-upon-https-call-to-a-page-with-wrong-certificate) in play 2.0.3 about this subject.
The [2.0.4 release](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401-play-20/milestones/155624-204) should fix the problem.
You may test it easily as a [release candidate has been announced](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/play-framework/22TX-nyC_CA/RGkvvZPZNNMJ).
You may find as well technical information on this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901816/accessing-ssl-secured-web-page-from-play-application).